# How to create view with a declare

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I need to create a view out of a query I wrote. This issue is that this one contains a declare and a CTE. Now I know that the CTE should be fine but that the declare raises an issue. A part of the code is:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW vw_NonApprovedTests AS
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = (SELECT MIN(ActionOn) FROM WFD) 
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = GETDATE();
WITH OrderDays as 
( 
    SELECT 
        CalendarDate = @StartDate
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        CalendarDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CalendarDate)
    FROM 
        OrderDays WHERE DATEADD (MONTH, 1, CalendarDate) <= @EndDate 
),
Calendar AS
(
    SELECT
        EndOfMonth =  EOMONTH (CalendarDate) 
    FROM
        OrderDays                 
) 

SELECT etc.......
```

The error it gives is:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure vw_NonApprovedOrWithdrawIntegrityTests, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.

I use this to calculate certain results in the rest of the query. These results need to be put in a view so they can be used in PowerBI for a dashboard. Is there a way for me to make this work?

Comment: You're creating a `VIEW`, it can't have variables. A `VIEW` is a pseudo-table defined by a *single* statement ending in a `SELECT`.

Comment: Side note, I also strongly recommend using a inline tally, or an actual Calendar table over an rCTE to do it; an rCTE performs very slowly compared to the other 2.

Comment: Would a temporary table work for this ? Because I cant just add a table to the database and I never used an inline tally before.

Comment: No, you can't define a temporary table in a `VIEW`. Again, ***single*** statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by just replacing your variables with your statements that assign them, i.e.

```
WITH OrderDays AS 
(   
    SELECT CalendarDate  = MIN(ActionOn) 
    FROM   WorkFlowDetails 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT CalendarDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CalendarDate)
    FROM   OrderDays 
    WHERE  DATEADD (MONTH, 1, CalendarDate) <= GETDATE()
), ....
```

As has been suggested in the comments though, a [Calendar table](https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/) is going to make this a lot easier and a lot more performant:

```
SELECT  Date
FROM    dbo.Calendar
WHERE   Date >= (SELECT MIN(ActionOn) FROM WorkFlowDetails) 
AND     Date <= GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in the comments, you can't define a variable in a `VIEW`. A `VIEW` must be made up of a *single* statement that results in a `SELECT`; variables therefore can't be defined as that's 2+ statements.

As I also mention, I suggest against an rCTE for creating a calendar. They are *slow* and if your results need more than 100 rows you may well get errors if you don't define the `MAXRECURSION` value in your `OPTION` clause of the outer query.

Instead use an inline tally or a calendar table to get the needed dates. I use a tally here, but I personally recommend the latter (though with no sample data, this is untested):

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW vw_NonApprovedOrWithdrawIntegrityTests AS

    WITH N AS(
        SELECT N
        FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
    Tally AS(
        SELECT 0 AS I
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
        FROM N N1, N N2, N N3), --1,000 rows
    Calendar AS(
        SELECT TOP (SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH,MIN(ActionOn),GETDATE()) FROM dbo.WorkFlowDetails)
               EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,T.I,WFD.ActionOn)) AS EndOfMonth
        FROM Tally T
             CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(ActionOn) FROM dbo.WorkFlowDetails) WFD)
    SELECT ...;
```